# Css Div left 100% sticks out of the parent div

Tags: html, css

I'm new to CSS and spend some time trying to get this working

```css
.parent{
    position:relative;
    top:0;
    left:0;
    background:blue;
    width:300px;
    height:300px;
}.container{
    position:relative;
    width:100%
}.right{
    position:absolute;
    top:0;
    left:100%;
    background:red;
  width:20px
}.left{
    position:absolute;
    top:0;
    left:0%;
    background:red;
  width:20px
}
```

```html
  <div class="parent">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="right">
       right
    </div>
   <div class="left">
       left
    </div>
   </div>
</div>
```

here is the fiddle  http://jsfiddle.net/nojs/k7bLyfyq/

I want to use left percent on both the divs, because the user can interact with them and that makes it better for me to do calculations

But if I put the div left to 100%, it causes it to render outside of the parent div.

Is there a way I can get it to conform to the parent div's width?

Comment: It's slightly unclear what you're trying to do. Is [this](http://jsfiddle.net/eL5rvnuk/) what you want...?

Comment: very unclear what you want your end result to be.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, when you use absolute positioning, it is positioning exactly where you are asking it to be. when you are saying 100% left, it is starting at 100% left, try adding `calc(100% - 20px)` the 20px is the width of the div itself.

```
.right{
    position:absolute;
    top:0;
    left: calc(100% - 20px);
    background:red;
    width:20px
}
```

see fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/k7bLyfyq/8/

Answer (score 0):

You can change the `.right` classes css attributes to create the desired effect. I change the `left:100%` property to `right:0%` and that allowed it to conform to the parent div. I have forked your [JSFiddle here :)](//jsfiddle.net/k7bLyfyq/14/).

Css and HTML:

```css
.parent {
  position: relative;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  background: blue;
  width: 300px;
  height: 300px;
}
.container {
  position: relative;
  width: 100%
}
.right {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: 0%;
  background: red;
  width: 20px
}
.left {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0%;
  background: red;
  width: 20px
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="right">
      right
    </div>
    <div class="left">
      left
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```